# Taylor expansion, series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Kinda stuck in  here too, would like to get some help!

Using Taylor expansion check if series :

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{e^\frac{1}{n} - e^\frac{1}{n+1}} $$

converges.

How do I approach this kind of exercise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Writen down the two Taylor expansions, subtract. Use the expression you get to show that the difference (and therefore its square root) is "small."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** with $e^x\sim_0 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ we have
$$e^\frac{1}{n} - e^\frac{1}{n+1}\sim\frac{1}{n^2}$$
so 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{e^\frac{1}{n} - e^\frac{1}{n+1}}\sim\frac{1}{n^2}$$
hence we have the convergence of the series by comparaison with Riemann series.